# Setting the Notebook to post Notes within in Evernote w/ RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, evernote

How do you make sure a **Note** is created in a specific **NoteBook** that is not the default?

In the client sample code that Evernote provides they show this

```
client = EvernoteOAuth::Client.new(token: authToken)

# List all of the notebooks in the user's account
note_store =  client.note_store
notebooks = note_store.listNotebooks(authToken)
puts "Found #{notebooks.size} notebooks:"
defaultNotebook = notebooks.first
notebooks.each do |notebook|
  puts "  * #{notebook.name}"
end

puts
puts "Creating a new note in the default notebook: #{defaultNotebook.name}"
puts
```

But the variable **defaultNotebook** does not get used again.  The note get's posted at the end with

```
createdNote = note_store.createNote(authToken, note)
```

I guess that in the demo the **defaultNotebook** is assumed for any notes that get posted.

There isn't a **setNotebook** method, but there is a **getNotebook** one.  Which the code demo for that is as follows.

```
client = EvernoteOAuth::Client.new(token: authtoken)
note_store = client.note_store

# We can ignore the creation here
notebook = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook.new
notebook.name = "Notebook 1402371893"
created_notebook = note_store.createNotebook(notebook)

# Here we see it is retrieved with the guid
note_store.getNotebook(created_notebook.guid)
```

So does the **getNotebook** method act as setting the notebook on the **note_store** instance which I can then create Notes within?  I have a feeling it's that simple.  I'll give it a try.

**EDIT**

Here are more details on the way I'm trying to implement the usage of setting the **Notebook** that receives the **Notes**:

```
client = EvernoteOAuth::Client.new( token: user.evernote_token )
noteStore = client.note_store

if user.evernote_notebook.length.zero?
    notebook = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook.new()
    notebook.name = "MyBook"
    user.update_attribute( :evernote_notebook,
        noteStore.createNotebook( user.evernote_token, notebook ).guid )
else
    noteStore.getNotebook( user.evernote_notebook )
end

createdNote = noteStore.createNote( user.evernote_token, note )
image.update_attribute( :evernote_guid, createdNote.guid )
```

The purpose is to know the **Notebook** is set and the **Note** will be placed there.

**NOTE THIS CODE WORKS --BUT-- The Note's in the wrong folder.**  It's in default and not the one I selected.

Here's the working answer

---

```
note = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new()
client = EvernoteOAuth::Client.new( token: user.evernote_token )
noteStore = client.note_store

if user.evernote_notebook.length.zero?
    notebook = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook.new()
    notebook.name = "MyBook"
    user.update_attribute( :evernote_notebook,
        noteStore.createNotebook( user.evernote_token, notebook ).guid )
end

note.notebookGuid = user.evernote_notebook 

createdNote = noteStore.createNote( user.evernote_token, note )
image.update_attribute( :evernote_guid, createdNote.guid )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you make sure a Note is created in a specific NoteBook that is not the default?

If you want to create a note in a specific notebook, just set the 'notebookGuid' attribute of the note.

```
note.notebookGuid = created_notebook.guid
```

If you don't explicitly set the notebookGuid attribute, the note will be created in the default notebook of the account.

The getNotebook method only retrieves the notebook you specified.

Comment: When you say note, do you mean note_store?  You say "set the attribute"... but that's what this whole question is.  It seems you're assuming I know how this is handled.

Comment: I think you may have been referring to note from the sample code.  Is that correct?

Comment: I was finally able to find what you're referring to.  Your note is an instance of `Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new` ... I tried note.methods and saw the `notebookGuid=` method.  And it works.  I originally tried it as `notebookGuid()` and that failed.  Why I did that I don't know.